# LOAD DATA INFILE jump autoincrement

Tags: php, mysql, csv

In a new empty table, I import a CSV file by following these steps:

**Database**
ID (autoincrement) PRIMARY; name; age

**CSV file**
Hernan; 34
Mariano; 12

**PHP/MySQL Query**
...
(name, age)
SET (ID = DEFAULT)

The CSV file contains **50,000** records. When finished, the next autoincrement should be **50,001**, but instead, in my App the next autoincrement is eg **68,020** or **62,153** or **65,448** ...

If the CSV file contains the ID column
1; Hernan; 34
2; Mariano; 12

After import **50,000** records, the next autoincrement its OK **(50,001)**

Why the IDs jumps in my work?

(Tested on localhost Appserv)

---

Is there any way in one single query do this?
(col1, col2, @ID)
@ID = 1; <----- Where I can put this?
SET (ID = @ID + 1)

**EDIT #1**

In my system you can create an event like an EXPO, in this event there are for example 3 types of signups (visitors, participants and staff)... in each signup type I need to be distinct code ranges (Visitor start at 5.000, Participants start at 15.000 and staff start with 25.000), in this case yo can see a code and then know what type of signup is that person and the secuential ID gave me an idea of how advanced is the signup records (ID 17.532 => Participant and aprox is the 2.530 signup from this signup type). All my system works perfectly only this "bug" for de LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: why do you care about this? in general you should not care about the actual ID value. if you have special constraints regarding the ID, you should probably use an additional field for it in the DB, separate from the primary key in the table (which is on auto-increment). if it is only about these 50'000 records, then it might be most simple to append the ID in the file, with a tool like `awk`, for example.

Comment: @hoijui, I understand your point. CSV regenerate, with a column for IDs is an option and can do it from Excel, but is an extra step (Made by a human) in the system that will give the user each time he has to import bases and the idea was to automate tasks. On my system, imports would be made all the time. Besides just seems wrong IDs jump like this. IDs need to be sequential because they have to render a visual barcode. After importing, manual loading would be made one by one. (49999 - 50000 - 67422-67423) This is wrong

Comment: if you do it in excel it is manual work, but if you use AWK (for example) you can automate it (easily). if you convert the number into a visual bar-code, why does it matter that the IDs are in sequence? it sounds like it is just an idea/feeling you have. Usually IDs are here for computers to differentiate entries, not to look orderly for humans when stacked together. Do not make your life harder then it has to be. ;-)

Comment: I edit my question with more information about the process of the system.

Comment: You see my 2cond (sub) question? Is there any way in one single query do this? (col1, col2, varID) varID = 1; <----- Where I can put this? SET (ID = varID + 1)

Comment: i am not sure what you mean. you want to auto-create IDs on the go while inserting into the DB? putting additional meaning to IDs is a bad idea (this roughly comes down to violating DB normalization). you should have an additional field indicating the signup type. IDs should only be used to differentiate entries, nothing more. this is why you are running into the problem you present here.

Comment: OK, forget the system and the IDs, the question now is: how can define in a variable SET (For other column than ID, for example _code) in the query itself with sequential value and indicate where start? ... (_name, _age, ID, _code) SET (ID = DEFAULT, _code =?)

Comment: you should supply this as a value for each entry. if you do not yet have them, generate them before entering into the DB. if you need them to start where you left of last time, keep an extra table in the DB where you store `lastCodeValue` (or `nextCodeValue`).

Comment: glad it worked out! :-)
last advice from me for now: you can also up-vote comments, if they were useful. ;-)